# Did Mayor Bowser declare a state of emergency over a health insurance issue?

Tags: united-states, executive-order, washington-dc, state-of-emergency, health-insurance

Radio station WTOP is [reporting](https://wtop.com/dc/2021/09/bowser-declares-public-emergency-in-dc-over-expiring-medicaid-contract/) that Washington, DC mayor Muriel Bowser has declared an "emergency" over a health insurance contracting issue. WTOP calls the order a "public emergency" and a "health systems emergency", but does not specifically state that it constitutes a State of Emergency as was called in 2020 over COVID-19.

It appears that Mayor Bowser's [actual order](https://wtop.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Mayors-Order-Declaring-Emergency.pdf) of September 1 calls it a "Health Care Resources Emergency".

My question is, did DC really enter a State of Emergency over a health insurance funding or legal issue, or is this some other type of order that just happens to have the word "emergency" in it? If it is not a State of Emergency order, what kind of executive order is it?

Comment: This would also fit on skeptics FYI.

Answer (score 3):

Yes; this order is a declaration of a public emergency in accordance with [§7–2304](https://code.dccouncil.us/dc/council/code/sections/7-2304.html) of the Code of the District of Columbia. This is the same type of declaration as was made in response to COVID-19 by Mayor Bowser in [Mayor's Order 2020-045](https://mayor.dc.gov/sites/default/files/dc/sites/mayormb/release_content/attachments/MO.DeclarationofPublicEmergency03.11.20.pdf) in March 2020 that you mentioned in your question, although not a public health emergency as was declared in [Mayor's Order 2020-046](https://mayor.dc.gov/sites/default/files/dc/sites/mayormb/publication/attachments/MO.DeclarationofPublicHealthEmergency03.11.20.pdf) under [§7–2304.01](https://code.dccouncil.us/dc/council/code/sections/7-2304.01.html).

Incidentally, DC is still in this original COVID-19 public emergency; [Mayor's Order 2021-096](https://coronavirus.dc.gov/sites/default/files/dc/sites/coronavirus/page_content/attachments/Mayors-Order-2021-096.pdf) ended the public health emergency, but extended the public emergency to October 8th.

This is not, however, the same type of state of emergency as [President Trump declared](https://trumpwhitehouse.archives.gov/briefings-statements/president-donald-j-trump-approves-district-columbia-emergency-declaration/) in DC in January 2021 - this was made under Title V of the [Stafford Act](https://www.fema.gov/sites/default/files/2020-03/stafford-act_2019.pdf), codified in [42 U.S. Code §5191](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/42/5191).